# Count lines and text strings in muliple csv files in linux and pipe to a csv file

Tags: linux, shell, csv

How would i traver though a folder containing multiple cvs files and:

1. Count non-empty lines
2. Count lines containing:
   a. "Time Out"
   b. "Mortality"
   c. "Init"

An pipe that to a csv file in the format:

Filename  "Line Count"  "Time Out"   "Mortality"   "Init"

in command line in Linux?

Edit:

```
wc -l ./*.csv > result.txt
```

And was able to get the count of the lines, but am unsure about find strings as stated above.

I edited according to shellcheck.net and got this:

```
#!/bin/bash

find ./ -type f -exec cat {} > /tmp/file.tmp \;
cmd /tmp/file.tmp | grep Time Out | grep Mortality | grep Init > /tmp/file2.tmp
wc -l /tmp/file.tmp
rm /tmp/file.tmp
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Remember we're not here to do your code work. But if you show us you did some research and started coding something, we will help you go the right direction.

Comment: Your question is unclear - you will need to think more clearly about what you mean. For example, you say you want to count lines containing `a`, `b`, `c` but do not indicate if you mean *all three* need to appear on the line or *any one* of them. Answerer has assumed you want all three on same line.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this script (may not be optimal for periodic use):

```
!/bin/bash

find ./ -type f -name "*.csv" -exec cat {} \; | grep Time Out | grep Mortality | grep Init > /tmp/file.tmp
wc -l /tmp/file.tmp
rm /tmp/file.tmp
```

Comment: Well it produces a 13 GB file out of 30 500KB size files

Comment: Time Out, Mortality and Init should be in ""

Comment: This is really not very good. Try running it through `shellcheck.net`.

Comment: Somehow i would have though that you just went trough one file at the time and then piped the count results to a csv file

Comment: i improved the "script" a little bit so you dont have to store the whole data and get your result quicker, but i am sure there are still better ways to do it...

Comment: produces zero byte tmp.file